# Get Items out of a tuple when the type of one of the parts is unknown

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to take a dynamic object that could be a two part `Tuple` and get the value out of it.  Normally, this would be easy, but in this case, the second part of the `Tuple` could be anything.  (Really it could be literally ANYTHING.)

This is what I tried to do in LinqPad to test it.

```
// This could be a Tuple<String, String>, Tuple<String, MyCustomClass>
// The second part of the tuple could be anything.
dynamic variable = new Tuple<String, int>("Test", 123); 

if (variable is Tuple<string, dynamic> tupleVar)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tupleVar.Item1}, {tupleVar.Item2.ToString()}");
}
```

I was hoping that the dynamic in `is Tuple<string, dynamic>` would allow it to match on anything for the second value.  But it treats dynamic as a type and will only match (or cast) if the created type is also a dynamic.

**Is there a way to know that my dynamic object is a two part `Tuple`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```cs
is ITuple tuple when tuple.Length == 2
   && tuple[0] is string
```

And fetch:

```cs
dynamic val = tuple[1];
```

One gotcha: it won't work if the `string` is `null`.

Comment: Works great in LinqPad, but ITuple is not in .NET Standard 2.0.    It was added in to .NET Standard 2.1.  I know I tagged this .net core 3.1, but I also have to support .NET Standard 2.0.  Going to have to go with the name check.  Still this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I should have kept digging a bit longer.  Looks like this will work:

```
dynamic variable = new Tuple<String, int>("Test", 123); 

if (variable?.GetType()?.Name=="Tuple`2")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable?.Item1}, {variable?.Item2?.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: I like the compare to ITuple better (from Marc's answer).  I am accepting that one, but it does not work in .NET Standard 2.0, so I will leave this one here.

Comment: FYI you may be better off checking "isgenerictype" and then "getgenerictypedefinition" against `typeof(Tuple<,>)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do the test with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0). It works even with `Tuple<,>` class, not only with the new [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)s:

```
dynamic variable = new Tuple<String, int>("Test", 123);

if (variable is (string name, var value)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{name}, {value}");
}
```

Where `value` is implicitly typed as `object?` (see: [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)).

The reason why this is possible is probably due to some compiler magic. There is a [System.TupleExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tupleextensions?view=netcore-3.1) declaring deconstructors and conversion extension methods; however, the pattern matching expression above also works when there is no `using System;` in our code. But the documentation says (see link above):

> Although these methods can be called directly, they are primarily intended for use by the C# compiler in creating and deconstructing tuples.

Note: there seems to be no advantage in using `dynamic` here. If you don't intend to call members of types unknown at compile time, simply use `object`.

Comment: The more I look at it, I really like this method.  But it seems to need .Net Standard 2.1 to work.  When I put it in a .Net Standard 2.0 project it says `object` is missing a `Deconstruct` method.  To put that in I am back where I started needing the ability to make the cast to a `<string, object>`  (works great in .Net Standard 2.0 though!)

Comment: IT doesn't need any .Net Standard. ValueTuples are support out of the box since .Net Framework 4.7 and in .Net Core. If you have a pre-4.7 Version, you can download the System.ValueTuple NuGet package. And you need C# 8.0 for the pattern matching part. In the (old) .Net Framework project, you must edit the project file (*.csproj) manually and the line `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to the first `<PropertyGroup>`, since you cannot select C#8.0 in the Visual Studio. (There is no drawback. It works perfectly.)